# How to requests all sizes in stock - Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to request all the sizes in stock from Zalando. I can not quite figure out how to do it since the video I'm watching
showing how to request sizes look different than min.
The video that I watch was this. [Video - 5.30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6g37-2o6KY)

Does anyone know how to request the sizes in stock and print the sizes that in stock?

The site in trying to request sizes of: [here](https://www.zalando.dk/nike-sportswear-air-max-90-sneakers-ni112o0bt-a11.html)

My code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

session = requests.session()

def get_sizes_in_stock():
    global session
    endpoint = "https://www.zalando.dk/nike-sportswear-air-max-90-sneakers-ni112o0bt-a11.html"
    response = session.get(endpoint)

    soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")
```

I have tried to go to the **View page source** and look for the sizes, but I could not see the sizes in the page source.

I hope someone out there can help me what to do.

Comment: Do you mean across all colours which is more complicated?

Comment: @QHarr I just want to know how I can see what shoe sizes there are in stock.

Comment: But this varies by colour. Do you only want the initial default colour in stock sizes or do you need to know them by colour?

Comment: @QHarr I just want to get the colour I have selected and see if it is in stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizes for the default color of shoe are shown in html. Alongside this are the urls for the other colors. You can extract these into a dictionary and loop, making requests and pulling the different colors and their availability, which I think is what you are actually requesting, as follows (note: I have kept quite generic to avoid hardcoding keys which change across requests):

```
import requests, re, json

def get_color_results(link):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers).text
    data = json.loads(re.search(r'(\{"enrichedEntity".*size.*)<\/script', r).group(1))
    results = []
    color = ""
    for i in data["graphqlCache"]:
        if "ern:product" in i:
            if "product" in data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]:
                if "name" in data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"]:
                    results.append(data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"])
                if (
                    color == ""
                    and "color" in data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"]
                ):
                    color = data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"]["color"]["name"]
    return (color, results)


link = "https://www.zalando.dk/nike-sportswear-air-max-90-sneakers-ni112o0bt-a11.html"
final = {}
color, results = get_color_results(link)
colors = {
    j["node"]["color"]["name"]: j["node"]["uri"]
    for j in [
        a
        for b in [
            i["family"]["products"]["edges"]
            for i in results
            if "family" in i
            if "products" in i["family"]
        ]
        for a in b
    ]
}
final[color] = {
    j["size"]: j["offer"]["stock"]["quantity"]
    for j in [i for i in results if "simples" in i][0]["simples"]
}

for k, v in colors.items():
    if k not in final:
        color, results = get_color_results(v)
        final[color] = {
            j["size"]: j["offer"]["stock"]["quantity"]
            for j in [i for i in results if "simples" in i][0]["simples"]
        }

print(final)
```

---

**Explanatory notes from chat:**

1. Use chrome browser to navigate to [link](https://www.zalando.dk/nike-sportswear-air-max-90-sneakers-ni112o0bt-a11.html)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to view page source
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search for 38.5 in html

   The first match is the long string you already know about. The string is long and difficult to navigate in page source and identify which tag it is part of. There are a number of ways I could identify the right script from these, but for now, an easy way would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

link = 'https://www.zalando.dk/nike-sportswear-air-max-90-sneakers-ni112o0bt-a11.html'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(link, headers = headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')

for i in soup.select('script[type="application/json"]'):
    if '38.5' in i.text:
        print(i)
        break
```

Slower method would be:

```
soup.find("script", text=re.compile(r'.*38.5.*'))
```

4. Whilst I used bs4 to get the right script tag contents, this was so I knew the start and end of the string denoting the JavaScript object I wanted to use `re` to extract, and then to deserialize into a JSON object with `json`; this in a re-write to use `re` rather than `bs4` i.e. use `re` on entire response text, from the request, and pass a regex pattern which would pull out the same string
5. I put the entire page source in a regex tool and wrote a regex to return that same string as identified above. See that regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/n8OYTd/1)
6. Click on right hand side, match 1 group 1, to see highlighted the same string being returned from regex as you saw with BeautifulSoup. Two different ways of getting the same string containing the sizes

[image]

7. That is the string which I needed to examine, as JSON, the structure of. See in json viewer [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?#left=cloud.5834c8a72fcb4e9d988b866f5c9ef9d5)
8. You will notice the JSON is very nested with some keys to dictionaries that are likely dynamic, meaning I needed to write code which could traverse the JSON and use certain more stable keys to pull out the colours available, and for the default shoe colour the sizes and availability
9. There is an expand all button in that JSON viewer. You can then search with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for 38.5 again

[image]

10a) I noticed that size and availability were for the default shoe colour

10b) I also noticed that within JSON, if I searched by one of the other colours from the dropdown, I could find URIs for each colour of show listed

[image]

11. I used Wolf as my search term (as I suspected less matches for that term within the JSON)

[image]

You can see one of the alternate colours and its URI listed above

12. I visited that URI and found the availability and shoe sizes for that colour in same place as I did for the default white shoes
13. I realised I could make an initial request and get the default colour and sizes with availability. From that same request, extract the other colours and their URIs
14. I could then make requests to those other URIs and re-use my existing code to extract the sizes/availability for the new colours
15. This is why I created my `get_color_results()` function. This was the re-usable code to extract the sizes and availability from each page
16. `results` holds all the matches within the JSON to certain keys I am looking for to navigate to the right place to get the sizes and availabilities, as well as the current colour
17. This code traverses the JSON to get to the right place to extract data I want to use later

```
results = []
color = ""
for i in data["graphqlCache"]:
    if "ern:product" in i:
        if "product" in data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]:
            if "name" in data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"]:
                results.append(data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"])
            if (
                color == ""
                and "color" in data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"]
            ):
                color = data["graphqlCache"][i]["data"]["product"]["color"]["name"]
```

18. The following pulls out the sizes and availability from results:

```
{
    j["size"]: j["offer"]["stock"]["quantity"]
    for j in [i for i in results if "simples" in i][0]["simples"]
}
```

19. For the first request only, the following gets the other shoes colours and their URIs into a dictionary to later loop:

```
colors = {
    j["node"]["color"]["name"]: j["node"]["uri"]
    for j in [
        a
        for b in [
            i["family"]["products"]["edges"]
            for i in results
            if "family" in i
            if "products" in i["family"]
        ]
        for a in b
    ]
}
```

20. This bit gets all the other colours and their availability:

```
for k, v in colors.items():
    if k not in final:
        color, results = get_color_results(v)
        final[color] = {
            j["size"]: j["offer"]["stock"]["quantity"]
            for j in [i for i in results if "simples" in i][0]["simples"]
        }
```

21. Throughout, I update the dictionary final with the found colour and associated size and availabilities

Comment: Hey @QHarr I'm wondering how you did it. If you will and have time, will you so explain it more in details how you did it for me?

Comment: It would be my pleasure. I might start with some broad comments, see where your questions are and potentially elaborate on broad comments?

Comment: Is there a bit in particular you would like an an explanation on sooner rather than later?

Comment: Yea, how you get the colors and sizes from the website. And I want to know if you used the network tab and how you analysis it.

Comment: I would also like to know if I need to do more things on it such as getting it in the basket, how to do it if I need to use your code.

Comment: The first question I can give more detail on. The second is more a new question. For the first, in short, no. I viewed the source code of the start webpage (to find the initial size list) , a regex online tool (to find the right regex to isolate the necessary JS object from that long string you were referring to in the comments/from the entire response), and a couple of different JSON viewers (to understand how the JSON deserialized object - from reading in regex match string, is structured, as it is very nested and complicated to navigate.)

Comment: Okay, but you were looking at source code where it was just long lines, how could you overlook it? and see what information you needed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244936/discussion-between-qharr-and-robert-tacchini).

Answer (score 2):

The sizes are in the page

I found them in the html, in a javascript tag, in the format

```json
{
    "sku": "NI112O0BT-A110090000",
    "size": "42.5",
    "deliveryOptions": [
        {
            "deliveryTenderType": "FASTER"
        }
    ],
    "offer": {
        "price": {
            "promotional": null,
            "original": {
                "amount": 114500
            },
            "previous": null,
            "displayMode": null
        },
        "merchant": {
            "id": "810d1d00-4312-43e5-bd31-d8373fdd24c7"
        },
        "selectionContext": null,
        "isMeaningfulOffer": true,
        "displayFlags": [],
        "stock": {
            "quantity": "MANY"
        },
        "sku": "NI112O0BT-A110090000",
        "size": "42.5",
        "deliveryOptions": [
            {
                "deliveryTenderType": "FASTER"
            }
        ],
        "offer": {
            "price": {
                "promotional": null,
                "original": {
                    "amount": 114500
                },
                "previous": null,
                "displayMode": null
            },
            "merchant": {
                "id": "810d1d00-4312-43e5-bd31-d8373fdd24c7"
            },
            "selectionContext": null,
            "isMeaningfulOffer": true,
            "displayFlags": [],
            "stock": {
                "quantity": "MANY"
            }
        },
        "allOffers": [
            {
                "price": {
                    "promotional": null,
                    "original": {
                        "amount": 114500
                    },
                    "previous": null,
                    "displayMode": null
                },
                "merchant": {
                    "id": "810d1d00-4312-43e5-bd31-d8373fdd24c7"
                },
                "selectionContext": null,
                "isMeaningfulOffer": true,
                "displayFlags": [],
                "stock": {
                    "quantity": "MANY"
                },
                "deliveryOptions": [
                    {
                        "deliveryWindow": "2022-05-23 - 2022-05-25"
                    }
                ],
                "fulfillment": {
                    "kind": "ZALANDO"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you parse the html with bs4 you should be able to find the script tag and extract the JSON.

Comment: Thank you it helped a lot but when I look at the source code it is a long line code is it possible you can get it a little more manageable just like you have sent here?

Comment: @RobertTacchini I'm interested in this too, I think it because he used `import json` and then printing the json result like: `print(json.dumps(x, indent=4))` - but, I would like to know his answer.

Comment: Ohh yea cool. But we just need to wait until @Lukas Schmid answer

Answer (score 0):

Always check if an hidden api is available, it will save you a looooot of time.

In this case I found this api:

- https://www.zalando.dk/api/graphql

You can pass a payload and you obtain a json answer

```
# I extracted the payload from the network tab of my browser debbuging tools
payload = """[{"id":"0ec65c3a62f6bd0b29a59f22021a44f42e6282b7f8ff930718a1dd5783b336fc","variables":{"id":"ern:product::NI112O0S7-H11"}},{"id":"0ec65c3a62f6bd0b29a59f22021a44f42e6282b7f8ff930718a1dd5783b336fc","variables":{"id":"ern:product::NI112O0RY-A11"}}]"""

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.zalando.dk")

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json"
}

conn.request("POST", "/api/graphql", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
res = res.read() # json output
```

`res` contains for each product a json leaf containing the available size:

```
"simples": [
        {
            "size": "38.5",
            "sku": "NI112O0P5-A110060000"
        },
        {
            "size": "44.5",
            "sku": "NI112O0P5-A110105000"
        },
        {
            ...
```

It's now easy to extract the informations.

There also is a field that indicate if the product got a promotion or not, cool if you want to track a discount.